# find the application that consuming large memory

Tags: linux, memory

How to find which application is consuming large memory?
Is there any other way than using top?

Comment: What is wrong with `top`?

Answer (score 1):

you can pipe the output of ps and sort the column of memory depending on the requirement.

```
ps aux | sort -r -k4
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you could specify your OS  (e.g. Ubuntu 12.04) and system(e.g. desktop/server) to help identify potential tools. For instance I can run 'gnome-system-monitor' which gives me a GUI display where I can sort by any of user, cpu, memory and other fields.